# using an ID of one table more than once into another table

Tags: php, sql

I have being working on this kind of movie store application in which i need to record a new movie entry in form of VHS and DVD copies,example i have 5 new DVD copies and 3 new VHS copies of lets say Batman the movie.I need to record the copies in the Films Table and Copies Table so that later on i may be able to search how many copies(VHS and DVD) i have of the Batman movie in my store.Am having difficulties in pulling out the right codes for accomplishing the given task.

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO copies (film_id,format,film_c) VALUES (last_insert_id(),'VHS','$vhs')"; mysql_query($sql2);
$sql3="INSERT INTO copies (film_id,format,film_c) VALUES (last_insert_id(),'DVD','$dvd')"; mysql_query($sql3);
```

This is what i originally wrote.But it worked fine with the VHS part but when it comes to the second query of the DVD copies the query fetches the last_insert_id() of the Copies table instead of the Films table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving the previous id in a php variable.

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
$sql2="INSERT INTO copies (film_id,format,film_c) VALUES ($id,'VHS','$vhs')"; mysql_query($sql2);
$sql3="INSERT INTO copies (film_id,format,film_c) VALUES ($id,'DVD','$dvd')"; mysql_query($sql3);
```

Comment: Thank you lyn headly it worked perfect just like i expected,i cant tell how relieved i am thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Between the queries, use **mysql_insert_id()** to hold the id in your script

Answer (score 0):

This is because last_insert_id() gets the id from the very last insert statement. When you did your first insert, it caused the value of last_insert_id() to change:
see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id for details on how to use last_insert_id(). It may be helpful to retrieve the value from the database and save it locally, or store it in an sql variable